# ¿Como ordenar una lista usando más de una propiedad e imprimirlo por pantalla?

Tags: c#, linq

Mi consulta es: ¿Cómo concateno dos datos del mismo tipo en una misma lista y los ordeno?

Yo tengo la siguiente lista (datos.txt):

```
ID  NOMBRE  APELLIDO    TIPO
01  JAVIER  GOMEZ   DNI
02  PEDRO   RODRIGUEZ   DNI
03  PAULO   NUÑEZ   LIC
04  PABLO   ARIAS   LIC
05  ALFONSO CAÑUELAS    DNI
06  CARLOS  SABEL   CEDULA
07  VICTOR  COSTA   CEDULA
```

Lo que deseo hacer es concatenar NOMBRE Y APELLIDO en un mismo dato.

Lo que tengo realizado hasta ahora es esto; una clase para definir estos datos:

```
public class Datos
{
    public int ID;
    public string Nombre;
    public string Apellido;
    public string Tipo;
}
```

Y la lista creada con estos datos:

```
   List<Datos> personas = (from p in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Usuario\pc\SO\datos.txt").Skip(1) 
                                   let parts = p.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                   where parts.Length == 4
                                   select new Datos
                                   {

                                       ID = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0].ToString()),
                                       Nombre = parts[1].ToString(),
                                       Apellido = parts[2].ToString(),
                                       Tipo = parts[3].ToString()
                                   }).ToList();
```

**Lo que yo necesito hacer es Ordenar esta lista por Nombre y Apellido, ¿Como puedo lograr esto, sin perder a su vez el dato TIPO de la lista e imprimirlo por pantalla?**

```
        var agrupado = personas.GroupBy(x => x.Nombre.Join(x.Apellido));
```

Se me habia ocurrido utilizar el Concat o Join pero me da error.

Ya que puedo utilizar `var agrupado = personas.GroupBy(x => x.Nombre);` pero me queda sólo ordenado por Nombre o Apellido (si cambio Nombre por Apellido ), quiero que quede ordenado por Ambos.

**SALIDA DESEADA**

```
ID  NOMBRE  APELLIDO    TIPO
05  ALFONSO CAÑUELAS    DNI
06  CARLOS  SABEL   CEDULA
01  JAVIER  GOMEZ   DNI
04  PABLO   ARIAS   LIC
03  PABLO   NUÑEZ   LIC
02  PEDRO   RODRIGUEZ   DNI
07  VICTOR  COSTA   CEDULA
```

Espero haberme expresado correctamente.
Un saludo.

PD: Quizas lo de concatenar los datos no sea necesario yo lo pregunto porque encare el problema por ese lado pero si hay otra solucion bienvenido sea.

Comment: Entonces, ¿ la pregunta se resume en que quieres ordenar la lista `List<Datos> personas` por nombre y apellido? ¿Probastes `OrderBy`?

Comment: Se podria decir que si y que no porque yo encare el problema por concatenar el caso que se pueda de otra manera cambio la pregunta. El tema es que OrderBy me ordena o por Nombre o por Apellido. ¿O puedo juntar ambos?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir "imprimir *por pantalla*"?

Comment: ...tal vez ayudaría si muestras un ejemplo de cómo se debería ver el resultado.

Comment: @sstan Realizado la salida deseada.

Comment: No entiendo la lógica de la salida deseada. Es como si estás ordenando por `Tipo`, pero no en orden alfabético.

Comment: @sstan era tarde ya en mi pais, arreglado, Ordenado por Nombre y Apellido con su respectivo Tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta de @sstan es correcta para la pregunta inicial. Pero tras las aclaraciones, lo que quieres es ordenar alfabéticamente los clientes pero dentro de cada tipo. Por lo tanto, lo primero que hay que hacer es agrupar por tipo, y posteriormente ordenar dentro de cada grupo:

```
var agrupado = personas.GroupBy(x => x.Tipo); 
foreach (var grupo in agrupado) 
{ 
    var ordenado = grupo.OrderBy(x => x.Nombre + x.Apellido); 
    foreach (var elemento in ordenado) 
    {  
         Console.WriteLine(($"& {elemento.Nombre} & {elemento.Apellido} & {elemento.Tipo}"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hola Pikoh. Gracias por tomar la releva y haber entendido el problema. :) En lo personal, todavía estoy confuso porque en la salida deseada expuesta en la pregunta, no veo que los resultados estén agrupados por `Tipo`.

Comment: @sstan es normal que no lo entiendas, tras la ultima edición se entiende menos. Si miras el historial, la anterior edicion, verás que los nombres estaban ordenados dentro de cada tipo (los de dni ordenados, los de cedula ordenados...) Ahora, yo tampoco lo entiendo :)

Comment: Ah, ya veo :) Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

Para ordenar una lista, obviamente, puedes usar `OrderBy`.

Si necesitas ordenar por más de una columna, necesitas combinar el `OrderBy` con `ThenBy`:

```
personas.OrderBy(p => p.Nombre).ThenBy(p => p.Apellido)
```

**Edición**

Sigo sin entender del todo la salida deseada mencionada en tu pregunta, porque parece que, por tu descripción y por la respuesta que aceptaste, quieres que los resultados estén agrupados por `Tipo` y luego ordenados por `Nombre` y `Apellido`.

Si este es el caso, todavía no encuentro nada en lo que pides que exija el uso de `GroupBy`. En realidad, otra forma de expresar lo que pides es que quieres ordenar por `Tipo`, luego por `Nombre`, y finalmente por `Apellido`, lo que se puede lograr de esta manera:

```
foreach (var persona in personas.OrderBy(p => p.Tipo)
                                .ThenBy(p => p.Nombre)
                                .ThenBy(p => p.Apellido))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{persona.Id}\t{persona.Nombre}\t{persona.Apellido}\t{persona.Tipo}");
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, y se podria hacer con el GroupBy ? Que quede unido digamos NOMBRE Y APELLIDO en un "Grupo" o Solo con OrderBy se puede ? Para luego utilizar expresion.Key y que se me impriman en orden...

Comment: `GroupBy` y `OrderBy` cumplen 2 objetivos completamento distintos. Tendrías que explicar mas claramente lo que estás tratando de lograr con el `GroupBy`. Yo pensaba que la idea era simplemente ordenar por esos 2 campos y que el `GroupBy` era simplemente una manera que estabas intentando lograrlo. Pero si solo buscas ordenar, ¿para qué usar 
 `GroupBy`?

Comment: Por si requiero hacer otras operaciones con el archivo. Ejemplo: Luego con el OrderBy para imprimirlo tendria que poner:  `foreach (var cli in agrupado)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{cli.ID} \t {cli.Nombre} \t {cli.Apellido}");
            }`
En cambio con GroupBy solo utilizo {cli.Key}. Ya que si utlizo OrderBy luego no puedo realizar operaciones como Max, Min, etc...

Comment: Sigo sin enteneder. A menos que tu lista tenga personas repetidas, usar `GroupBy` no tiene sentido, porque resultaría en agrupaciones de una sola persona en cada grupo. De nada sirve usar `Max`, `Min` etc. con grupos de un solo elemento. Si sigues pensando que necesitas `GroupBy`, edita la pregunta y agrega un ejemplo concreto donde piensas que `GroupBy` puede ayudar. Pero a mi me suena que estás tratando de forzar la herramienta que no corresponde a la situación.

Comment: Editado, le agregue un dato para que veas a que quiero llegar. Que dificil es expresarse con solo escritura. Me dan ganas de reir y llorar...

Comment: Agregando al comentario expuesto por @sstan cuando haces una consulta de selección es una coincidencia que los datos parecieran que vienen en orden pero no es así los datos vienen desordenados se nota cuando ya tienes una buena cantidad de registros, es por eso que es recomendable usar `ORDER BY`, te recomiendo que estudies conceptos de lo que te están recomendando si no te vas a estrellar contra la pared.